# Comparing date parameters in C# switch statement

Tags: c#, datetime, switch-statement

For some reason i cannot compare two date parameters in the Switch statement in C#.
The same comparison works perfectly fine in `if` and `else if` statement but not in `switch`.

Example :

```
switch (DateTime.Today.ToString())
{
    case DateTime.Today.AddDays(-10) <= DateTime.Today;
}
```

Comment: You need to review the syntax for switch, because you are not using it anything like it was designed for.  Case ends in a colon, not semicolon and you are using ToString() in the switch() so the cases must all be strings, aka, "5/13/2011 6:25 PM" is what Today.ToString() would do.

Answer (score 2):

A `case` statement must be a compile-time constant ([C# spec and example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)):

> Each case label specifies a constant value.

Unfortunately, you won't be able to use a `switch` for comparing `DateTime`. It's uglier, but using `if`'s is the better option here.

Comment: Your statement indicates that `case default(DateTime):` should work, since `default(DateTime)` is a compile-time contant, but it does not work.

Comment: i don't think default(DateTime) is compile time constant. AFAIK it's implemented as DateTime.MinValue, which is a static constant..

Comment: @YetAnotherUser, huh, it seems you're right. What confused me was the fact that you can use `default(DateTime)` as a default value for an optional parameter. Although I don't think it's implemented by calling `DateTime.MinValue`.

Comment: OK, restating my previous complaint: Your statement indicates that `case null:` should work when you switch on `DateTime?`, since `null` is a compile-time contant, but it does not work.

Comment: @svick - Yes you are right - it's default is created like any other struct not by calling DateTime.MinValue. Also to answer your next comment - 'null' is not valid for 'ValueTypes' though it is for reference types.

Comment: @YetAnotherUser , `null` *is* valid for nullable value types, like `DateTime?` (short for `Nullable<DateTime>`).

Comment: All this discussion seems off topic. The OP was applying `switch` to a `string`, not `DateTime`. It stands that `DateTime` cannot be used in a `case` statement. However, `case null:` is supported for `string`.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote switch case wrong, check more info on it here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t(v=VS.100).aspx

Note also that switch cases works on constants so I think `DateTime` will not work with it, u will get compile error

Answer (score 1):

you can do switch statements on DateTime values by converting them to long  (dateTime.Ticks)

Answer (score 0):

Section 8.7.2 of the C# 4 specification states that the type on which it's possible to switch has to be:

> `sbyte`, `byte`, `short`, `ushort`, `int`, `uint`, `long`, `ulong`, `bool`, `char`, `string`, or an enum-type, or […] the nullable type corresponding to one of these types

or a type that is implicitly convertible to one of those types, except to `bool`.